# How to implement EXT JS store tree list from SQL Query Data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arraylist, extjs

I need to implement a view with expandable options.

**My SQL data** :

```
 rows: SQLResultSetRowList
 0: {Name: "Namashivya", Master: 500, sub: 2}
 1: {Name: "Namashivya", Master: 500, sub: 5}
 2: {Name: "Guru", Master: 1000, sub: 2}
 length: 3
```

**My store** :

```
Ext.define('master.store.history', {
extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
xtype       : 'historyStore',
requires    : ['master.Db', 'master.model.history'],
config :
{
    model   : 'master.model.history'
},
loadData    : function()
{
     var meObj=this;
     var sqlString = "SELECT master.Name, master.Master, sub.sub FROM master INNER JOIN sub ON master.Id=sub.masterID where sub.status='1';";
     master.Db.selectQuery(sqlString, meObj.callbackLoadData, meObj);
 },

 callbackLoadData   : function(results, scope){
 console.log(results);
  // need to implement tree list store config

  }
 });
```

Anyone can help me how to implement the tree list

**Example of static data**

```
store: {
    root: {
    expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: 'detention',
            leaf: true,
        }, {
            text: 'homework',
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: 'book report',
                leaf: true,
            }, {
                text: 'algebra',
                leaf: true,
            }]
        }, ]
    }
},
```

My dynamic data how to show root in name column and master and sub column in child.

Thank you

Comment: Are you directly calling sql query from UI code or is there any server api between this process ?

Comment: directly calling in sql and no api